# Overriding Render in Rails 3 - Request for design review / code refactor

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, controller, render

I'm looking for an extensible way to inject functionality into a controller.

```
module Social
    module Request
        def self.included( base )
            base.alias_method_chain :render, :social
            base.alias_method_chain :process_action, :social
        end

        def process_action_with_social(method_name, *args)
            @action = method_name
            process_action_without_social(method_name, *args)
        end

        def render_with_social(action = nil, options = {}, &blk)
            if @action == "new"
                          # do something social
            end
            render_without_social
        end
    end
end

class RequestController < ApplicationController
    include Social::Request

    def new     
        @request = RecommendationRequest.new
    end
end
```

This code above is working, but I'm pretty sure it's not optimal ruby. I'm going to be creating different modules for each controller, probably a bunch of them, actually.  The only code that will be unique to each controller, is render_with_social.

So my questions are:

1. Is there a way to pull the other two methods out, so I can not repeat myself?  (Sorry, this is the first time I've used modules in ruby).
2. Is there a way to do this without having to put the include Social::Request in the RequestController at all?  (I want to be able to remove these modules, and have my controller continue to work as if nothing had happened)
3. If I wind up having different suites of these Metrics::Request, Scoring::Request etc, what would be the best way to approach having a single location where I specify what modules will be mixed in to which controllers?

Thanks all.